# ActionNotSupportedException occurred after change EndpointAddress

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, wcf-binding

I am working with WCF and Silverlight. i want to change EndpointAddress with code behind dynamically:

```
EndpointAddress endpointAdress = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);
var proxy = new ServerConnectionClient(context);
proxy.Endpoint.Address = endpointAdress;
```

Connection opened successful but after call a method from service occurred ActionNotSupportedException.

> **Web.config**:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://MyIpAddress:4502/engine/net" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" contract="CTMSConnection.IServerConnection"
        name="NetTcpBinding" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Above config generated after Add Service Reference.

Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is very easy. **you have to generate code exactly same with `Web.Config`**.

you must be use the below code:

```
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("net.tcp://YourIpAddress:4502/CTMSEngine/net");

        System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding customBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();

        System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement BMEelement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpTransportBindingElement TcpTelement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpTransportBindingElement();
        customBinding.Elements.Add(BMEelement);
        customBinding.Elements.Add(TcpTelement);
        TcpTelement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        TcpTelement.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;

        proxy = new ServerConnectionClient(customBinding, endpointAddress);
```

Comment: i want to change url only. but i will test your code.

Comment: you can not create new ServerConnectionClient and then change endpointAdress.